# Is there a way to install packages via a a queue even when there is another instance of an installation or upgrade is running?

Tags: package-management

Many times there is the problem, that I have only a small bandwith connection, and when running a `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` or similar with a big download volume and then stumble upon a program that I want to install additionally via packagemanagement, then I have to remember that myself. Even worse when I have to add a ppa...

Is there a way to add the PPAs and add packages for installation to a queue even when there is another instance of an installation or upgrade is running?

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I am not bound to aptitude, apt-get or synaptic, but would prefer a CLI solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a package manager wait if another instance of APT is running?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running)

Comment: Nope, the old question is never a duplicate of the new one, but feel free to mark that other one as a duplicate of mine.

Comment: Question age is not a factor in determining which is a dupe of which.

Comment: Of course it is. This question wouldn't have been asked, if the other question were about 2 years older. So this question is *not* a duplicate of the new one. But yes, I can see that the answers to the new question are much more exhaustive, so I would be fine with other ways to link. But flagging this as duplicate makes me appear to be to stupid to look for similar questions before posting.

Comment: Whether it makes you appear stupid is entirely your perspective. I don't really care either way.

Comment: Yeah... Power of the 30k... And the 290 aren't even heard...

Answer (score 4):

You can safely interrupt apt during the download phase.

Otherwise, poor man's queue?

```
while pgrep aptitude; do sleep 10; done && aptitude install foo
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but here is a little script called `apt-iq` (apt install queue) that I made. It essentially runs apt-get commands in the background once it becomes possible.

```
#!/bin/bash
# apt-iq - An install queue system for apt-get.
# usage: apt-iq [aptgetargs].
#        apt-iq --nosep [aptgetargs]
# Run with --nosep to NOT split off and free the terminal.
if [ $1 == '--nosep' ]; then
  while :; do
    lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1
    [ ! $? = 0 ] && break
    sleep .01
  done
  apt-get ${@:2} -y -qq
  echo "DONE."
else
  $0 --nosep $@ &
fi
```

To use:

```
sudo apt-iq install foo
sudo apt-iq remove bar
```