# How to make a package manager wait if another instance of APT is running?

Tags: command-line, apt

I have seen many softwares such as Update Manager and Synaptic Package Manager, they wait if some other program is using the `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` and is locked. How can we do this through the Terminal? I saw `apt-get`'s manual but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: well you can do several apt-get commands. Like `sudo apt-get install packagename && sudo apt-get update` and they will happen automatic after each others.

Comment: Does this not do that: `sudo apt-get install packagename1 packagename2 packagename3`  ?

Comment: (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463498/terminate-and-disable-remove-unattended-upgrade-before-command-returns if you are in the special case where you are trying to wait for boot time apt to finish on Ubuntu 18.04 and up)

Comment: apt does that in Ubuntu 20.04 and later, I suppose. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277255/111181)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [the `aptdcon` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/aptdcon) to queue up package manager tasks by communicating with aptdaemon instead of using apt-get directly.

So basically you can just do `sudo aptdcon --install chromium-browser` or whatever and while that command is running you can run it again but install different packages and apt-daemon will just queue them up instead of erroring out.

This is especially useful if you're doing a long upgrade or something and want to keep installing packages or if you're scripting something together and want to make sure installing things will be more reliable.

Comment: Can `aptdcon` be run such that it accepts any prompts as `apt-get -y` does?

Comment: `yes | aptdcon --hide-terminal --install "package"` Hide Terminal is needed, else piping `yes` will cause issues.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it requires installing `aptdcon`. I'm working on a bootstrap script that does the initial setup of a VPS, where a background process is doing some initial setup as well. I can't install `aptdcon` until I can work around the lock.

Comment: @FakeName for initial server configuration you probably want to use cloud-init: http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @JorgeCastro - My issue in this case is a VPS'es bringup script running in the background on newly deployed VPSes, which then collides with my own cloud setup system (using salt-stack). Adding /more/ dependencies isn't really the proper solution.

Comment: Basically, I'm having issues with the salt-stack deploy procedure fighting with Vultr's slightly strange deploy system. See https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/37062 Liberal use of wait-for-dpkg from the other answers appears to have solved the issue, with no install needed.

Comment: what package is `aptdcon` in?

Comment: // , @ctrl-alt-delor https://askubuntu.com/q/1012576/150944

Answer (score 59):

You can make `apt-get` to learn to wait if another software manager is running. Something similar with the behaviour from the next screen cast:

[image]

#### How I made it?

I create a new script called `apt-get` (wrapper for `apt-get`) in `/usr/local/sbin` directory with the following bash code inside:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

i=0
tput sc
while fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
    case $(($i % 4)) in
        0 ) j="-" ;;
        1 ) j="\\" ;;
        2 ) j="|" ;;
        3 ) j="/" ;;
    esac
    tput rc
    echo -en "\r[$j] Waiting for other software managers to finish..." 
    sleep 0.5
    ((i=i+1))
done 

/usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/apt-get
```

Before to test, check if everything is ok. The output of `which apt-get` command should be now `/usr/local/sbin/apt-get`. The reason is: by default, the `/usr/local/sbin` directory is placed before `/usr/bin` directory in user or root `PATH`.

Comment: thats really a direct hit to my question. thanks :)

Comment: How your script manages stacked instances of apt-get? Like, before it finishes I launch 5 more apt-get?

Comment: @Braiam Sincerely, I don't know; I'm not a good tester. Did you test it? If problems appears, the script can be improved by creating a new lock with timestamp when a new instance of the script starts (just an example - there are also many other ways).

Comment: wow! eloquent. works like a charm with everything I've thrown at it so far! Two thumbs up... this should just be part of the package :D

Comment: That's perfect! I've had problem where I use AWS cloudinit to install packages on a new server, but Ubuntu does some `apt` stuff on boot, so my `dpkg` command failed due to locked dpkg db. I've put this one-liner  in my cloudinit userdata: `while fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done; dpkg -i package.deb` and it works great.

Comment: using `inotify` would improve this script.

Comment: I sorta want to use a snippet of this code in a larger script. However, I am not familiar with controlling terminal cursor and I don't understand why you need the `tput sc` and `tput rc` because I'd assume the cursor just automatically goes to the end of the line, anyway, right? And for the "loading bar" rewrite effect, that's covered by `echo -en` so can you explain what it's doing with the cursor? I tried testing it and somehow my VM system got all screwed up. Running two `sudo bash testme.sh -y install dpkg bash gcc build-essential perl git-all autotools-dev cmake libffi-dev ; echo "$?"`'s

Comment: I tested it without the `tput` lines and it restores the cursor anyway even when I try to type things. Are those necessary for output to logs or consoles or something? Or do some terminals just behave differently and you're being safe?

Comment: more effective to use `grep -qFx /var/lib/dpkg/lock < <(lslocks -no PATH)`

Answer (score 28):

A very simple approach would be a script that waited for the lock to not be open. Let's call it `waitforapt` and stick it in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
#!/bin/sh

while sudo fuser /var/{lib/{dpkg,apt/lists},cache/apt/archives}/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do
   sleep 1
done
```

Then just run `sudo waitforapt && sudo apt-get install whatever`. You could add exceptions into `sudoers` to allow you to run it without needing a password (you'll need it for the `apt-get` so it's no great gain).

Unfortunately this doesn't queue things. Given that some of apt's operations are interactive ("Are you sure you want to remove all those packages?!"), I can't see a good way around this...

Comment: maybe `-y` to assume yes for all operations?

Comment: Thank you. I think I can use it better if I use alias help.

Comment: In not sure `-y` is desirable though.

Comment: I don't think you want to wrap `sudo fuser` in `[[ $(...) ]]`. It returns a zero exit code when the file is being accessed so that should be sufficient.

Comment: @Oli You could also do something like 
`sudo waitforapt && xterm -e "sudo apt-get install whatever"` to pop up a window when the lock is released.

Comment: Better to use `inotify`.

Comment: I found the following solution to be more complete, as there are several locks involved when working with apt-get:

`while sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do echo 'Waiting for release of dpkg/apt locks'; sleep 5; done; sudo apt-get -yy update`

Comment: For my task (an Ansible run), I need to simply wait until apt is free, and then the further tasks are taken care of in another way. So I just grabbed the script and put it into my process as a one-liner, in place of where I'd have a simple wait.

Answer (score 20):

Apart of the obvious `&&`, you may be looking for `aptdcon`. This tool is able to detect other instances of apt and wait them to finish:

```
sudo aptdcon --safe-upgrade
[/]  11% Waiting for other software managers to quit Waiting for aptitude
```

(I'm running aptitude somewhere else)

The advantage of this tool is that you can stock several actions consecutively without being worried of what you will be doing next. `aptdcon` is ideal for unattended scripts, and GUI installation, since you can allow the tool run in background as not to block your frontend.

The operations supported by `aptdcon` are:

- `--refresh`, `-c`: This is the equivalent to `apt-get update`. It updates your package list.
- `--install`, `--remove`, `--upgrade`, `--purge`, `--downgrade`. Each of them do as their names say. The name of the package(s) is mandatory. `-i`, `-r`, `-u`, `-p`: these are the short options for all except downgrade, who doesn't have one.
- `--safe-upgrade`, `--full-upgrade` are the counterparts to `apt-get`'s `upgrade`/`dist-upgrade` and `aptitude`'s `safe-upgrade`/`full-upgrade`. These doesn't need parameters.
- There are several others operations, which can be found in the manual. But, these are the most used by users interested in `aptd`. There are options that overlap with  what `apt-key`, `apt-cache`, `dpkg` do.

`apt-get` itself doesn't support such methods (to wait for other instances of apt), so `aptdcon` is the preferred solution to GUI's package managers: USC uses `aptd` as back-end, same as Synaptic. Other solution is `packagekit`, but it doesn't support the function that you are looking for (yet).

Comment: `aptdcon --install /path/to/pgk.deb` Works like `dpkg -i`, although I wasn't able to find this explicitly mentioned in the manual.

Comment: Can I use this in post-install script in a package ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira why would you use this in the ppst-install script? If post-install is being executed obviously apt is running.

Comment: I want to make postinstall install some special packages that are not in the repository. Is this possible ? I would include them in package and then the script would install them after installation finishes.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira again, why it would be necessary? The post-install scripts only runs when there's a package installation. I suggest you to [ask a question instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=debian,packaging,apt) and explain your case with more detail.

Answer (score 8):

Since 1.9.11 `apt` and `apt-get` have an option that lets you wait for the dpkg locks to be released.

Use the `DPkg::Lock::Timeout` option to set a timeout, in seconds, for an apt-get command. This example will wait for 60 seconds:

```bsh
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=60 install packagename
```

If you set that value to -1, it will keep waiting forever.

```bsh
sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=-1 install packagename
```

For more information see: [Waiting for apt locks without the hacky bash scripts](https://blog.sinjakli.co.uk/2021/10/25/waiting-for-apt-locks-without-the-hacky-bash-scripts/).  This option was [added to apt-get in February 2020](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/merge_requests/109).

Comment: The option works in Ubuntu 20.04 and later. The command generates one line of output for each second it waits unless you use `-q=2` which implies `-y` i.e. no asking for user confirmation.

Comment: Still the problem is that you can not make sure the package database stays intact during you decide which packages to operate before the apt command is executed.

Answer (score 4):

One-liner based on [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/373478/515251):

```
while sudo fuser /var/{lib/{dpkg,apt/lists},cache/apt/archives}/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately fuser doesn't do a lot for you when you are running in different unprivileged namespace containers like lxc.

Also, aptdcon is not installed by default (at least on 18.04) and backgrounds your task in a queue so you lose serialization.  This isn't insurmountable, but it does mean your automation needs to have some way to avoid flock errors in apt when installing aptdcon, and you'll need to have some sort of wait loops for anything you need to serialize after installing packages via aptdcon unless there is some sort of flag for that already.

What does work is flock. This should also work over NFS etc as it uses file system locking in the same way apt does, only with the -w seconds parameter it will wait on your lock instead of throwing an error.

So following the wrapper model, add this as apt-get in /usr/local/bin/ and share away.

This also has the benefit of limiting IO by not allowing parallelism on apt so you can let cron trigger updates at midnight everywhere without beating up the disk.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/flock -w 900 -F --verbose /var/cache/apt/archives/lock /usr/bin/apt-get $@
```

A very nice and simple feature request for apt-get would be a -w flag to switch to a blocking / wait lock.

Comment: apt uses fcntl, not flock, so this won't work. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077215/how-does-apt-get-use-var-cache-apt-archives-lock

Comment: This works perfectly and is a better option than using `fuser` as shown in many answers because `fuser` is still prone to race conditions between watching the lock and the target process grabbing the lock again. With `flock` the lock is acquired and then passed to the target process so it leaves no time for losing the lock in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

You could using a polling technique:

```
$ time (while ps -opid= -C apt-get > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done); \
  apt-get -y install some-other-package
```

Comment: better to use `inotify`

Answer (score 2):

I made a script which does this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# File path to watch
LOCK_FILE='/var/lib/dpkg/lock'

# tput escape codes
cr="$(tput cr)"
clr_end="$(tput el)"
up_line="$(tput cuu 1)"

CLEAN(){
    # Cleans the last two lines of terminal output,
    # returns the cursor to the start of the first line
    # and exits with the specified value if not False

    echo -n "$cr$clr_end"
    echo
    echo -n "$cr$clr_end$up_line"
    if [[ ! "$1" == "False" ]]; then
        exit $1
    fi
}

_get_cmdline(){
    # Takes the LOCKED variable, expected to be output from `lsof`,
    # then gets the PID and command line from `/proc/$pid/cmdline`.
    #
    # It sets `$open_program` to a user friendly string of the above.

    pid="${LOCKED#p}"
    pid=`echo $pid | sed 's/[\n\r ].*//'`
    cmdline=()
    while IFS= read -d '' -r arg; do
        cmdline+=("$arg")
    done < "/proc/${pid}/cmdline"
    open_program="$pid : ${cmdline[@]}"
}

# Default starting value
i=0

# Checks if the file is locked, writing output to $FUSER
while LOCKED="$(lsof -F p "$LOCK_FILE" 2>/dev/null)" ; do
    # This will be true if it isn't the first run
    if [[ "$i" != 0 ]]; then
        case $(($i % 4)) in
            0 ) s='-'
                i=4
                _get_cmdline # Re-checks the command line each 4th iteration
            ;;
            1 ) s=\\ ;;
            2 ) s='|' ;;
            3 ) s='/' ;;
        esac
    else
        # Traps to clean up the printed text and cursor position
        trap "CLEAN False; trap - SIGINT ; kill -SIGINT $$" SIGINT
        trap 'CLEAN $((128+15))' SIGTERM
        trap 'CLEAN $((128+1))' SIGHUP
        trap 'CLEAN $((128+3))' SIGQUIT

        # Default starting character
        s='-'

        _get_cmdline
        echo -n "$save_cur"
    fi
    # Prints the 2nd line first so the cursor is at the end of the 1st line (looks nicer)
    echo
    echo -n "$cr$clr_end$open_program"
    echo -n "$up_line$res_cur$cr$clr_end[$s] Waiting for other package managers to finish..."
    #echo -en "$cr$clr_end[$s] Waiting for other package managers to finish..."
    #echo -en "\n$cr$clr_end$open_program$cr$up_line"
    ((i++))
    sleep 0.025
done

CLEAN False

# This allows saving the script under a different name (e.g. `apt-wait`)
# and running it. It only imitates `apt-get` if it was launched as such
if [[ "${0##*/}" == 'apt-get' ]]; then
    exec /usr/bin/apt-get "$@"
    exit $?
fi
```

Save the above into `/usr/local/sbin/apt-get`. `apt-get` will then wait if another instance is already running.

Alternatively, save it as `/usr/local/sbin/apt-wait`, example usage:

```
apt-wait && aptitude
```

which will run `aptitude` after the current process holding the lock has exited.

> Example run:
>
> 1. First, an `apt-get` command is run, for example:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-get remove some_package
>    ```
> 2. Then, in another terminal, another command is run:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-get install some_other_package
>    ```
>
>    It will wait for the first command to finish then run. Output while waiting:
>
>    ```
>    [/] Waiting for other package managers to finish...
>          28223 : /usr/bin/apt-get remove some_package
>    ```

Comment: better to use `inotify`