# I need to check for dpkg lock before installing apps in a script

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, scripts

I have a problem with a script I wrote to install a bunch of apps, basically as it loops through an array of app names to install it checks them by doing:

```
dpkg -l | grep -q $i
```

and based on the $? will either install or skip the app. Trouble is for a few items it fails due to a dpkg lock, almost the whole list works, just half a dozen fail but work if you run the script again.

Is it possible to wait for dpkg to finish before running the 'apt-get install'?

For now I've added a 'sleep 0.5' between the 2 lines and this has stopped the problem but is obviously ugly and slower.

Thanks, 
Noki

Comment: How do I use this in a non-interactive script. This appears to need user input each time it queues up an application to install?

Comment: You should better ask on the concerned answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To identify processes using files or sockets you can use `fuser` command (see `man fuser` for more info). In case of `dpkg`, you can check for the lock as root with the following command:

```
fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: Your answer on [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running) is much better/helpful IMO.

Comment: @Jobin This answer only to the current question.