# Apt-get to retry downloading

Tags: apt

When using wget, `-c` is used to keep wget retrying to download, usually in the event of an internet interruption. What equivalent of `-c` can we use for apt-get to keep on retrying even in the case of unstable internet connection which keeps on getting disconnected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a package manager wait if another instance of APT is running?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running)

Comment: For wget, `-c` is used to *resume* downloads from where they left off. If apt-get is interrupted for any reason, just try it again. For more specific issues, please provide details. Also, check the man pages for wget, apt-get, and apt for the switches available to each.

Comment: Related: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: @DKBose Yeah except sometimes it doesn't keep everything it downloaded... I was 33% of the way once and when it restarted it went down to 27%

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [`man apt.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/apt.conf.5.html)

> Retries Number of retries to perform. If this is non-zero APT will
> retry failed files the given number of times.

```
echo 'Acquire::Retries "3";' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80-retries
```

Since apt 2.3.2, the default is 3.