# What provides aptdcon for Ubuntu 16.04? Which package do I install?

Tags: package-management

How do I install the `aptdcon` command to script aptitude package installation?

Someone else had a similar question here:

[How to make a package manager wait if another instance of APT is running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running#comment1520841_231859)

Comment: // , Well, I guess that's a little like saying that a question about Python loops is a duplicate of a question about how to run Python. Yes, you found the more general case, but is it a *duplicate*?

Comment: // , Maybe it's one for the meta guys

Comment: Yes. Look at the dozens of dupes that question already has.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fortunate enough to have installed it at some point, and could use `dpkg -S` and `which` to quickly find this.

```
$ which aptdcon
/usr/bin/aptdcon
$ dpkg -S $(which aptdcon)
aptdaemon: /usr/bin/aptdcon
```

If someone knows how to use apt or aptitude to accomplish the same thing, please chime in.

Update: Apparently I can install the `apt-file` package and run `apt-file update` then `apt-file search aptdcon` to achieve the same result.

For further info, you can check out the following
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=find+out+which+package+provides+a+command&t=canonical&atb=v106-3&ia=qa
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/equivalent-of-rpm-qf-command/