# How to wait on /var/lib/apt/lists/lock availability on unattended execution?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates

Please note: there're similar questions around, **but this specific scenario is unanswered**. Don't close this as a duplicate of 335794 or 1340943.

This is always reproducible, and this is about **apt lists lock** not about dpkg lock.

I'm running a series of automated tasks that perform some install through APT. The tasks are sequential (zero parallelism) but may invoke apt multiple times. At a certain point, when the script executes

```
sudo apt -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=60 update
```

I immeditately get this error output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock. It is held by process 1496 (packagekitd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

**this error goes away quite quickly** - if I retry after 10 seconds the operation (usually) succeeds, but sometimes it stays locked longer because packagekitd is doing who-knows-what.

My problem: **this is an unattended operation**. I'd like to have this automated, but I couldn't find a way to either:

- tell apt to wait until the lists lock is available, or
- to manually wait for the lock - I tried using **flock** even with an exclusive lock, but acquiring it seems to always succeed (it's probably using another locking approach)

Surely I could sleep every time. But this is flaky and it will makes the process quite slow.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 Intel 64bit

Comment: Did you try https://askubuntu.com/a/373478/158442? Or the `aptdcon` mentioned in the other answers there?

Comment: Seems like a possible race condition. Is this an automated new-install? Or does the same issue occur on old installs when you run the script?

Comment: It cannot be a race condition. All tasks are sequentials. If something "races" is something that packagekitd is doing on its own. The same issue happens every time I launch the script.

Comment: @muru the fuser approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

while sudo fuser /var/lib/apt/lists/lock >/dev/null 2>&1; do
   sleep 1
done
```

This worked. From [How to make a package manager wait if another instance of APT is running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running/373478#373478)