# Starting custom process after auto update completes - Apt-Get pauses custom install script

Tags: apt, 22.04, unattended-upgrades

A little background: I am trying to set up an automated install process in AWS that configures my servers with little intervention. I have it generally working in Ubuntu 18.04. However, in 22.04 (ARM) There are errors.

The problem: [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

A solution: [https://linuxconfig.org/disable-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux#:~:text=Open%20a%20command%20line%20terminal%20and%20then%20edit,the%20file%2C%20replacing%20whatever%20is%20currently%20in%20there%3A](https://linuxconfig.org/disable-automatic-updates-on-ubuntu-22-04-jammy-jellyfish-linux#:%7E:text=Open%20a%20command%20line%20terminal%20and%20then%20edit,the%20file%2C%20replacing%20whatever%20is%20currently%20in%20there%3A)

I have implemented the solution above. The issue is that when I run `apt list --installed`.

I still get: `unattended-upgrades/jammy,now 2.8ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]`.

In 18.04 the end of that line reads `[installed]`. Am I able to make the 22.04 version manual so the system sees it as such? I really don't want it to run at all on the first boot. This automated version locks up my ability to continue processing the server until I either reboot it or the process finishes. My automation breaks, where if I do it manually it works.

If I can't have that, I could also use a comment or two on knowing how to know that auto-install has finished on the first boot.

I am noticing that I have to press `enter` twice during the upgrade process even with the `-y` flag. Is this part of the issue? Or a different issue?

Thanks All!

UPDATE: My understanding of what is going on in the `apt list -installed` command is corrected from the comments.

My issues now are:

1. Is there a way I can start the process without using sleep and an arbitrary number?
2. How do I deal with apt-get upgrade needing me to press enter to continue my custom installations?

Comment: Let's make a quick correction on the output of `apt list`. The output `[installed,automatic]` does not mean that the software runs automatically. It means that the package is a dependency (it was pulled in automatically by apt).

Comment: An issue with trying to prevent apt from running is that you might be creating a race condition. It depends on your process, and might be subject to bugs...or features. Example: When I was doing something similar using cloud-init a few years ago, I found that apt ran anyway before my customizations were processed. My experience was that waiting until apt completed was the only sure way of getting uniform results. Perhaps your experience will differ.

Comment: Your first point is well taken. That is why I couldn't find anything on it. It would account for some reason for the differences between 18 and 22. You have a fair point in your second comment. My main worry is that the software that I install is a third-party app (of course) and it can be a bit... brittle... do any of you have suggestions of how to begin my process only after the auto-update has finished?

Comment: @LeviRCoding https://askubuntu.com/a/373478/158442 is what I use for my EC2 user data scripts. I write a wrapper function for apt using that, and use it everywhere in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Using Muru's link and reading there: [How to make a package manager wait if another instance of APT is running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running/373478#373478)

I went down to Mendhak's comment near the bottom and apparently, since 20.04, the functionality I need has been in `apt-get`.

His comment led me to: https://blog.sinjakli.co.uk/2021/10/25/waiting-for-apt-locks-without-the-hacky-bash-scripts/. Which is exactly the same application and issue that I am working with.

The short version is: `sudo apt-get -o DPkg::Lock::Timeout=60 install packagename`

Between the other thread and the external link, I had no shortage of options. Please support the posters there also.

Comment: Just a note that while this handles dpkg locks, you could potentially run into problems with apt's locks as well (IIRC it holds a lock on the cache while downloading packages, or updating package lists - don't remember which one exactly)