# Do not gave up on lock while running apt

Tags: apt, xubuntu, dpkg

I have a script that uses apt heavily and currently it faces a locking issue, as:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I want that apt tries to get the lock other than aborting. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do not use a query in your program and wait with the further execution until a lock is possible again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to install packages via a a queue even when there is another instance of an installation or upgrade is running?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92271/is-there-a-way-to-install-packages-via-a-a-queue-even-when-there-is-another-inst)

Comment: Or http://askubuntu.com/questions/132059/how-to-make-a-package-manager-wait-if-another-instance-of-apt-is-running

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, getting apt to not lock is impossible. The error is happening because the script is trying to run multiple apt sessions simultaneously. I think it would be best if you could modify the script so that apt operations are run after each other, in a queue maybe.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @Wilhelm's advice (which is good) if you are left with a stale lock file that will not go away (this happens some times) you must remove it manually.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

But be very careful that you have the path exactly correct as the `sudo rm -rf` will remove files (even system files) in use if you point it to them and can thus permanently break your system.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that.